# Alignment of colour scale within ggplot2 legend box

Tags: r, ggplot2, alignment, legend

I am trying to centre or right-align the colourbar within the legend box in ggplot2, but can't manage to do it. None of the examples I've seen say anything about it, but I presume it must be possible. See below. How can I move the colourbar so that it is under the 'm' of 'Cameron'?

[image: Colourbar left-aligned]

I have tried:

```
guides(colour=guide_colourbar(title.hjust=0.5))
```

and many other things, but none have the desired effect. Any advice?

N.B. I am not asking about aligning the legend box within the plot area.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way, you'll have to adjust the values to fit your plot.
Basically, the idea is to adjust the legend title and then move the whole legend box in the right position (this may require increasing the size):

```
+ theme(plot.margin=unit(c(1,7,1,1),"cm"),
        legend.position=c(1.2, .5))
+ guides(colour = guide_legend(title.hjust=-0.2))
```

Comment: I see. Following your idea, I just suppressed the native legend title, and added my own title in the correct position with `annotate`. Thanks.

Seems strange there's no easier way to do this.